# ASP.NET Core created signature does not verify in Delphi 2007

Tags: c#, delphi, signing

For years, we have used a DLL created in Delphi 2007 to generate and verify signatures for our licenses. We have now updated the service to an ASP.NET Core application, which is also generating the signatures from an option string. This signature still needs to be verified by the code in the Delphi 2007 DLL since older applications need to be able to do this. There is no way to update the way this is done in applications that have already been deployed.

On the .NET side, I use `RSACryptoServiceProvider` with the original private key. On the Delphi side, I use SteamSec (2007 version) and the `TstRSAPublicKey` component. The only settings I can find that are different are;

`SignEncoding` (`seEMSA4`)
`EncryptEncoding` (`eeEME1`)

Both cannot be found on the .NET component.

C# code looks like this:

```cs
var lcCspParams = new CspParameters { KeyContainerName = GeneralConsts.LicenseKeyTool };
using var lcRsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024, lcCspParams);

var lcData = lcConverter.OptionsBytes(RegistrationName);
var lcCryptedData = lcRsa.Encrypt(lcData, true);

using var lcSha256 = SHA256.Create();
byte[] lcHashed = lcSha256.ComputeHash(lcData);
var lcFormatter = new RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter(lcRsa);
lcFormatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA256");

var lcSignCode = lcFormatter.CreateSignature(lcHashed);

var lcResult = Convert.ToBase64String(lcSignCode);
return lcResult;
```

Comment: No idea what `lcConverter.OptionsBytes()` is, but what encoding does it convert to? Do you have any non-ASCII chars in `RegistrationName`?

Comment: lcConverter.OptionsBytes() converts the string containing the options for the license into a byte array. The Registration name is copied before this, also as a byte array. Together they form the byte array that has to signed.